# Text doesn't wrap when the font size is increased in react native

Tags: css, react-native, text

I'm trying to increase font size of title text an also make it wrap but, it does not wrap once I crease the font size. I want to make the heading text wrap and still be able to increase the fontzise. But `textAlign: "center"`  seems to have no effect on it.

Please, how can I achieve it as it is in the second Image?

This is my code currently.

```
function OnboardingScreen() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaScreen>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                
                <View style={styles.swiperContainer}>
                    <Swiper>

                        <View style={styles.slide}>
                            <Text style={styles.titleText}>Hello there,</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.textSubTitle}>Welcome to Sherz, We are glad to have you.</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.slide}>
                            <Text
                                // numberOfLines={2}
                                style={styles.titleText}>Easy, smart
                                and reliable</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.textSubTitle}>You don’t have to worry about
                                market hassle, we are here for you.</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.slide}>
                            <Text style={styles.titleText}>Hello there,</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.textSubTitle}>Welcome to Sherz, We are glad to have you.</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.slide}>
                            <Text style={styles.titleText}>Hello there,</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.textSubTitle}>Welcome to Sherz, We are glad to have you.</Text>
                        </View>

                    </Swiper>
                </View>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaScreen>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    image: {
        flex: 0.5,
    },
    closeIcon: {
        width: WP(5),
        height: WP(5),
        left: WP(90),
        top: HP(2),
    },
    swiperContainer: {
        flex: 0.5,
    },
    slide: {
        height: WP(15),
        width: WP(70),
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginTop: HP(5),
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },
    titleText: {
        fontSize: WP(8),
        // width: WP(70),
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        // backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
    textSubTitle: {
        fontSize: WP(4),
        marginTop: HP(2),
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
})
```

This is what I have achieved now

[image]

This is what I want to achieve

[image]